# Objective-C Should or possible for callback to be triggered many times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback

When I attach a callback as `reply:` in `WKInterfaceController +opendParentApplication:reply:` from my extension, `appDelegate` receives the callback as `reply:` in `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:`.

Can and Should I retain the callback in my `appDelegate` and call it multiple times whenever I want to send something to the caller (i.e. the extension)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can retain the callback in appDelegate. That will optimize the performance of your app.